# How to get Custom Entity associated fields in Subscriber? 'Mapping definition neither have entities nor collection' error

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I'm going to use Custom Entity associated fields in Subscriber. But I get this error:
`Mapping definition neither have entities nor collection.`

Subscriber.php:

```
class Subscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepository $myfilter_property_group_option_tagRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $myfilter_property_group_option_tagRepository)
    {
        $this->myfilter_property_group_option_tagRepository = $myfilter_property_group_option_tagRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductListingCriteriaEvent::class => [
                ['onListingCriteria', -200],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onListingCriteria(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $context = $event->getContext();
        $optiontags = $this->myfilter_property_group_option_tagRepository->search(new Criteria(), $context);
        $event->getContext()->addExtension('optionTags', new ArrayEntity($optiontags));
        
        // Further 
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('properties');
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('properties.group');

        $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
        $filters = $criteria->getExtension('filters');

        if (!$filters instanceof FilterCollection) {
            return;
        }

        $propertyFilter = $filters->get('properties');
        // More
```

services.xml:

```
<service id="MyFilter\Subscriber\Subscriber">
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
    <argument type="service" id="myfilter_property_group_option_tag.repository"/>
</service>
```

Does someone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Also there is already an extension for this entity created in administration component. Is it possible to use that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myfilter_property_group_option_tag` is based on a mapping definition, presumably mapping `property_group_option` and `tag` entities. Mappings themselves can't be fetched. Fetch the entities on either side of the mapping instead.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('myTags');

$tags = new TagCollection();
$options = $this->optionRepository->search($criteria, $context->getContext())->getEntities();
/** @var PropertyGroupOptionEntity $option */
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $extension = $option->getExtension('myTags');
    
    if (!$extension instanceof TagCollection) {
        continue;
    }
    
    $tags->merge($extension);
}
```